# Composition of category equivalence and limit creating functor preserves limit

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

Let $F:A\rightarrow B$ be an equivalence between categories and $H:B\rightarrow C$ be a limit creating functor.

Prove $HF$ is a limit reflecting functor.

I am stumped. I know I have to use the fact that $F$ is an equivalence between categories and use all of the extra structure that comes with such a functor, but I'm not really sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$H$ reflects limits - that's one part of the definition of creating them. $F$ preserves and reflects *everything* "categorical", including limits†. Finally, limit-reflecting functors are closed under composition.

Can you prove/follow the claims above?

†in fact, all fully faithful functors reflect limits

**Edit**: Here's the proof of the stronger statement in the footnote:

Let $F : A → B$ be fully faithful, $D : I → A$ a diagram, and $α : ΔL ⇒ D$ a cone such that $Fα$ is a limiting cone. We need to prove that $α$ is limiting itself, or in other words every other cone $β : ΔK ⇒ D$ needs to factor through $α$ via a unique morphism $φ : K → L$.

Since $F$ is fully faithful, the morphisms $K → L$ correspond exactly to morphisms $FK → FL$, which is a good thing because you know nothing about the former, and something about the latter.
In particular, you know there exists a unique morphism $ψ : FK → FL$ which factors $Fβ$ through the limiting cone $Fα$ (ie. $Fβ_i = Fα_i ∘ ψ$, for all $i$ in $I$).
Now let $φ$ be the unique morphism such that $ψ = Fφ$, and check that it really proves that $α$ is limiting.
Tell me if you need me to fill in any other details.

Comment: How would I prove F reflects?

Comment: I managed to prove that $\varphi$ is a good morphism between $K$ and $L$. But how do I prove the uniqueness? Would it be something along the lines of: Suppose $\theta$ also makes everything commute, then $F\theta$ would satisfy everything $\psi$ should, which would be a contradiction to the uniqueness of $\psi$?

Comment: Sure, that's exactly it. $Fθ$ must equal $ψ = Fφ$, and from there $θ = φ$ by faithfulness of $F$. 

The general point is, given a fully faithful functor you can move freely between it's domain and it's image; it establishes an equivalence between these two categories.